# Separate data and put them in an array (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a variable called `$name` and it contains something like this:

`$name = 'FName_LName_DataX_Number_www.website.com';`

I want to put all the data before the `Number` in an array withouth the underscores and the `Number` value too.

Something like this:

```
$array[0] = 'Fname Lname DataX';
$array[1] = 'Number';
```

`$name` examples:

```
$name = 'Roberto_Carlos_01_www.website.com';
$name = 'TV_Show_Name_785_www.website.com';
```

Comment: this is hard to split. first, you don't know how long the name is or how many words is the name so you rule out counting. next, if i were to base my "split" when it sees a number, what if the name had a number? like 2nd? 3rd? it would cut the name off.

Comment: I don't think in that, you are right, I think the only way is to format the name like this `Name-Name-Name_Number_www.website.com`.

Comment: in your example, you have 2 names in one, 3 names in the other. how would you know the user only has "3-worded names"?

Comment: NomikOS give the answer `is_numeric` is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is special to use regular expressions. But at any time that someone gives that kind of solution another someone say `regular expressions are evil!`. So let's play a little:

```
$index  = 0;
$array  = array();
$array0 = array();
$array1 = array();

$name = 'FName_LName_DataX_002_www.website.com';

$aux = explode('_', $name);

if (is_array($aux))
{
    foreach ($aux as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_numeric($value))
        {
            $index = $key;
            break;
        }
    }

    foreach ($aux as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key >= $index)
        {
            $array1[] = $value;
            break;
        } else
        {
            $array0[] = $value;
        }
    }

    $array[0] = implode(' ', $array0);
    $array[1] = implode(' ', $array1);
}

$name = 'TV_Show_Name_785_www.website.com';
result: 
array (
  0 => 'TV Show Name',
  1 => '785',
)

$name = 'FName_LName_DataX_002_www.website.com';
result: 
array (
  0 => 'FName LName DataX',
  1 => '002',
)

$name = 'Roberto_Carlos_01_www.website.com';
result: 
array (
  0 => 'Roberto Carlos',
  1 => '01',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use Regexp here. Try this:

```
<?php
$matches = array();
$name = 'Roberto_Carlos_01_www.website.com';
preg_match('/([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(\d+)_(.+)/', $name, $matches);
print_r($matches); // array elements 1-4 contain the sub-matches
?>
```

**Edit**

Sorry, didn't realize the input was variable.  Try this:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$matches = array();
$name = 'Roberto_Carlos_01_www.website.com';
preg_match('/([^\d]+)(\d+).+/', $name, $matches);

$array[0] = trim(str_replace('_', ' ', $matches[1])); // info before number
$array[1] = $matches[2]; // the number

print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but don't work correctly with more elements in the name.

Comment: It works but like Joseph say it dont work if the name have numbers like 2nd.

Answer (score -1):

First the best way would to be to put this data into an array using the php    explode() function

Use that like so:

```
<?

$data = explode("_" $name);

//Then get the data from the new array.
$array[0] = $data[0]." ".$data[1]." ".$data[2];
echo $array[0];
echo $data[3];
//Array index 3 would contain the number.
?>
```

This would get all of the data including the number. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I cant use it because I will print always the same array and with this I can't know how many arrays have the complete name.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I understand what you mean by this. Could you please explain?

Comment: I will use `$array[0]` to print the full name and  `$array[1]` to print the number.